# Pandas: select cell value using pd.at with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to select specific cell values from a Pandas Dataframe. I want to filter out rows with specific values in column A, and then get the values from column B.

From what I understand, the correct way to do this is to use `df.at`, so I've tried

```
df.at(df['Column A' == column_A_value]['Column B'])
```

but this doesn't work. I've also tried, as a hack,

```
str(['Column A' == column_A_value]['Column B'])
```

doesn't work either.

What is the right way to do this?

Edit:

What I'm trying to do is to output the values inside of a bigger loop, something like:

```
while condition:
    for val in some_column_A_values:
        print("{},{}".format('stuff', df.at(df['Column A' == val]['Column B'])), file=myfile)
```

Comment: That looks more like a `df.loc` case. `df.at` would be to access one value only. `df['Column A' == column_A_value]` returns an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Anton vBR has pointed out, this should solve your problem

```
filtered = df.loc[df['Column A'] == column_A_value]['Column B']
```

And if you like to get just one value you can do:

```
list(df.loc[df['Column A'] == column_A_value]['Column B'])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `item()` method also works if you need to get just one value

```
df.loc[df['Column A'] == column_A_value]['Column B'].item()
```

Note: Returns a `ValueError` if there are more than 1 elements in the underlying data